# Combining a GET and POST request through an API in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, post, google-apps-script, get, urlfetch

I am having trouble combining a GET and POST request in Google Apps Script. What I am trying to combine is below, but I keep getting errors.

```
function DBMdownload() {

var queryId = "xxxxxxx”;
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/doubleclickbidmanager/v1/queries/" + queryId;
var data = xxxxxxx);
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'muteHttpExceptions': FLAGS.SHOW_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS,
    'headers': {'Authorization': ('Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())}
     };

var options = { 
    'method': 'post', 
    'contentType': 'application/json', 
    'payload': payload, 
    'muteHttpExceptions': FLAGS.SHOW_HTTP_EXCEPTIONS,
    'headers': {'Authorization': ('Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())} 
     };

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Comment: "combine" in what way? make one request after the other? Where is `payload` defined? is that important? What errors are you getting?

Comment: More information in your question might make it much easier to answer. (Eg, what do you mean by "combine"? What does your code look like when you try it? What error do you get when you try it?...)

Comment: Yes, making one after another. The Google Apps Script documentation said to use Payload to download the JSON file.

Comment: so, what is payload? you haven't declared it. How are we supposed to know what the payload is? Your code doesn't even TRY to make the two requests anyway, it stops at one

Comment: I updated the script but not sure what to put as the data variable.

Answer (score 2):

updated::

1. not sure what is 'combine requests' but obviously you'll have to send them separately and each one should have it's own method and all the other fields of the request object. You can send several requests simultaneously with [UrlFetchAll](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests) method.
2. you don't have to stringify payload when sending a post request if it's JavaScript object and you're ok with default contentType. Here's an example from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)):

```
var resumeBlob = ...
var formData = {
  'name': 'Bob Smith',
  'email': 'bob@example.com',
  'resume': resumeBlob
};
// Because payload is a JavaScript object, it is interpreted as
// as form data. (No need to specify contentType; it automatically
// defaults to either 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
// or 'multipart/form-data')
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'payload' : formData
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', options);
```

Otherwise, you have to set contentType explicitly and provide stringified JSON as payload:

```
  var data = ...
  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'contentType' : 'application/json',
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };

  var reposnse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

3. you can acsess JSON data returned by post request by parsing the HTTP response data accessible via [getContentText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getContentText()):

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/");
var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```